# How to get Maximum value of X axis that will be visible on screen

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, jogl

I want know the Maximum value of x and y axis such that they are visble.

I have

```
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POINTS);      
 gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   
 gl.glVertex3f(MAX_X_TO_LEFT, 0.0f, 0.0f);  
 gl.glVertex3f(MAX_Y_TO_RIGHT, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
 gl.glEnd();
```

I want to set values of MAX_X_TO_LEFT,MAX_X_TO_RIGHT such that all three points are visible on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take your maximum 'screen' x value. (I.e., for a 1024x768 resolution, it might be 1024).
2. 'unproject' it. See this function for reference: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml

It's the reverse of the process that take your world coordinates and projects them on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

That will depend entirely on your projection and modelview matrices.